# Application icons for Flex mobile app targeting Android and iOS

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex-mobile, flash-builder4.5, multiscreen

The Adobe doc [Developing AIR applications for mobile devices](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac58d08f9112e26606ea8-8000) lists quite a few icons to be declared in an application descriptor file.

But when I try Export Release Build with the following myApp-app.xml:

```
<icon>
    <image16x16>assets/icons/16x16.png</image16x16>
    <image29x29>assets/icons/29x29.png</image29x29>
    <image32x32>assets/icons/32x32.png</image32x32>
    <image36x36>assets/icons/36x36.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>assets/icons/48x48.png</image48x48>
    <image57x57>assets/icons/57x57.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>assets/icons/72x72.png</image72x72>
    <image114x114>assets/icons/114x114.png</image114x114>
    <image128x128>assets/icons/128x128.png</image128x128>
    <image512x512>assets/icons/512x512.png</image512x512>
    <!-- 
    <image50x50>assets/icons/50x50.png</image50x50>
    <image58x58>assets/icons/58x58.png</image58x58>
    <image100x100>assets/icons/100x100.png</image100x100>
    <image144x144>assets/icons/144x144.png</image144x144>
    <image1024x1024>assets/icons/1024x1024.png</image1024x1024>
     -->
</icon>
```

I get the error message (regardless if deploying for Android or iOS) unless I comment the 5 lines as above:

```
error 103: application.icon.image50x50 is an unexpected element/attribute
error 103: application.icon.image58x58 is an unexpected element/attribute
error 103: application.icon.image100x100 is an unexpected element/attribute
error 103: application.icon.image1024x1024 is an unexpected element/attribute
error 103: application.icon.image144x144 is an unexpected element/attribute
```

My question is what to do here? Moving those 5 icons underneath `<android>....</android>` or `<iphone>....</iphone>` doesn't help either.

Using Flash Builder 4.7 beta under Windows 7 / 64 bit.

Comment: It is really odd to me that the ones you commented out at the ones that are causing compiler errors.  Are you using Flex or the new ActionScript compiler?  Check your images; I had one situation where exporting the images from Illustrator actually made them 1 pixel off; so instead of 50x50 it was 49x49.  I brought said images in Photoshop and resized them if memory serves me.

Comment: You've misunderstood me: they're causing me the error message, that's why I have to comment them out. Also, I'm using Gimp, dimensions seem to be ok. It's about Flash Builder rejecting certain `<image__x__>...</image__x__>` tags for some strange reason.

Comment: Are you using Flex or the new ActionScript compiler?  My app (Flex 4.6 + AIR 3.4) compiles fine with those image sizes in there.

Comment: Using Flash Builder 4.7 beta + default Flex 4.6.0 SDK (not sure which AIR version it is). Do you have/know a good guide on updating to AIR 3.4 or using compiler?

Comment: I think 4.6 comes w/ AIR 3.1 or 3.2 . Here is a good guide to update the AIR version: http://www.jasonsturges.com/2012/08/overlay-adobe-air-3-4-sdk-in-flash-builder-4-6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to update the version of AIR used within your SDK.  Those new icon sizes are not supported in the version of AIR included in Adobe Flex 4.6 [or Apache Flex 4.8].

Instructions for [updating the AIR SDK within Flex](http://www.jasonsturges.com/2012/08/overlay-adobe-air-3-4-sdk-in-flash-builder-4-6/) can be found here.  Generically do this:

1. Download current SDK and unzip it
2. Copy and files and folders from your unzipped directory to the root of your Flex directory
3. Update the name of the Flex SDK in the “flex-sdk-description.xml” file.

Comment: Thanks, updating to AIR 3.5 has helped: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html

Comment: For anybody else coming here with this problem using adt on the command line, make sure that when you update your AIR SDK to 3.5+, you also update your XML Descriptor to 3.5: <application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.5" minimumPatchLevel="0">, or it will act like it's still using the older version of AIR.